# Equivalence of Edit Distance and Alignment Distance

Tags: algorithm, distance, proof, edit-distance, string-algorithm

[image: definitions]

[image: proof]

(from: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.417/Slides/alignment.pdf)

The slide on the 11th page talks about how the **Edit Distance** and the **Alignment Distance** are equivalent.

I understand how to prove that the Edit Distance will always be less than or equal to the corresponding Alignment Distance. We can always construct a sequence of edits from a given alignments that gives the same result. Since the Edit Distance sequence is the shortest possible, the corresponding sequence is at least as long.

I don't understand how to prove the reverse inequality. Can anyone provide the proof? Apparently one needs to use the triangle inequality to prove it.

On a similar note, are there any resources that treat this topic rigorously? For example, I want proofs of why these two distances satisfy the axioms of metric spaces.

Comment: Their approach is that if you execute the sequence of edit operations, you get a valid alignment. And that alignment is better (or the same) than the other alignment.

Comment: One approach would be to follow slide 17- it states the traditional recurrence that defines/computes alignment distance as a theorem. You can prove that the same recurrence holds for edit distance, as well.